# Problem plotting data in Matlab (setting month and year in the x-axis)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following table structure in MATLAB:

```
Year  Month  datapoint
1990   1        5
1990   2        7
.
.
.
1995   12       3
```

I want to plot this with datapoint on y-axis and something like 1990_1, 1990_2... on the x-axis.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the appearance of the XAxis by getting the handle to that object with the *get* function, and then modifying the properties directly.

```
% Create example table
t = table();
t.Year = repelem(1990,72,1);
t.Month = [1:72].';
t.datapoint = [5:76].';

plot(t.datapoint)

% Get x axis
xaxis = get(gca,'XAxis');

% Format tick labels
xaxis.TickLabels = compose('%d_%d',t.Year,t.Month);

% Format interpreter
xaxis.TickLabelInterpreter = 'none';

% Limit number of ticks
xaxis.TickValues = 1:numel(t.datapoint);
```

---

---

As per your comment, to only see every 12th label:

```
indx = 1:72;
indx(12:12:72) = 0;
indx(indx > 1) = 1;
xaxis.TickLabels(find(indx)) = {''}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect! Is there also a way to only show some of them? I have 72 data points, so ideally I would like only every 12th label to be visible.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work, post doing this the no. of ticks is correct but there are no labels.

Comment: @NikhilJain Works for me. What MATLAB are you on?

Comment: @NikhilJain This should probably be a separate question by the way. The original question was answered already.